# Manipulation of a large list

Tags: parallelization, apple-silicon

I am doing a few fairly simple math operations on a large array with dimensions of 21600 by 43200 integers (ByteCount of 22,396,780,880 bytes) and I'm surprised at the long time that the computations are taking.
I'm on a new MacBook Pro with 64 GB of memory and 10 core Apple M1 Max, and the latest Mathematica 13.0.1.
The command to add a small portion of the array:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Total[Table[
   If[ datall[[i, j]] > 0, datall[[i, j]], 0], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 
    100} ], 2 ] ]
```

took 41.3 seconds!

```
 AbsoluteTiming[
 Sum[If[ datall[[i, j]] > 0, datall[[i, j]], 0], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 
   100} ] ]
```

Took 197 seconds.

SumParallel took much longer, as did using ParallelTable (In fact it's still running after 24 minutes with an estimated 20 minutes more to run.)

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[
  datall[[i, j]] = If[ datall[[i, j]] < 0, 0, datall[[i, j]] ],
  {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]]
```

took 1.598 seconds
while  ParallelDo took 11.95 seconds.

```
    AbsoluteTiming[
     ParallelDo[
      datall[[i, j]] = If[ datall[[i, j]] < 0, 0, datall[[i, j]] ],
      {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]];
    Output:= {11.9495, Null}
```

Thankfully, by zeroing out the negative values first, I'm able to do a total with

```
AbsoluteTiming[ Total[ datall[[1 ;; 100, 1 ;; 100]], 2] ]
```

in expectedly short times (0.0009 seconds).

But I would have expected that this would be a good use of Parallelism and would not have been nearly so slow.
Are there other suggestions I should try?

Steve

Comment: Try `Clip[data, {0, 1}]` to zero out the negative values. You can use `Total[Clip[data[[;;100, ;;100]], {0, 1}], All]` to do your limited sum.

Comment: @CarlWoll I think `1` should be replaced with `Infinity`. Another solution can be `Total[Ramp[Take[data, 100, 100]], All]`.

Comment: Note that all the operations you're using—`Do`, `Sum`, `Table`—are all sequential. You'll generally get better performance out of more functional operations that act on "all the data at once". So, taking the region of the array you want, via `Part` (`[[ ]]`), `Take`, or `Extract`, then `Map` (`/@`)-ing a function over it or, better, using a function like `Clip` with the attribute `Listable`, will be faster!